# How to solve List view range error that is retrieved from the firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm displaying a request list from the database, and when a request created I got an error before displaying it, i thought the error was because of the null i added condition to check and it did not work also

this is my code

```
 UserCubit.get(context).requestFriends.isEmpty
                ? Container(
                
                child:
                Center(child: Text('You have no requests')))
                : Container(
              height: height * 0.3,
              child: Flexible(
                child: ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                     
                      return Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                              
                            Text(
                                "${UserCubit.get(context).requestFriends[index]['nameSender']}"),
                            
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (_, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20),
                        child: Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: lightgrey,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: UserCubit.get(context)
                        .requestFriends
                        .length ==
                        0
                        ? 1
                        : UserCubit.get(context)
                        .requestFriends
                        .length),
```

and here a pic of the error

[image: Error]

I think this is what causing the error [image: debug console]

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are giving giving itemcount as 1 when the length is 0.

Try Changing the itemCount from

```
itemCount: UserCubit.get(context)
                        .requestFriends
                        .length ==
                        0
                        ? 1
                        : UserCubit.get(context)
                        .requestFriends
                        .length
```

to

```
itemCount : UserCubit.get(context)
                        .requestFriends
                        .length
```

Comment: it was like you said but i changed in hopes it helps but it didn't

Comment: Can you share your error log, though a pastebin ?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by error log, but i added something from my debug console it might help you understand the error. No i didn't use pastebin, not even sure what it is :)

Comment: That didn't help. Can you check if 
`UserCubit.get(context).requestFriends[index]` is having a valid size inside The builder ?

Comment: I solved the problem. I had a contact image in the listviews and the list retrieved the user info before the image. I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Here

```
UserCubit.get(context).requestFriends[index]['nameSender']
```

You can't use ['nameSender'] after index. just decode it before using it. Hope it helps

Comment: i had the same exact code on another page and it was working just fine.